# Remove duplicate string and display like a tree?

Tags: bash, filter

I am having an output that we need to edit so we can have it with removed repeated entries, it's more like being a tree we have the parent device with its child devices and each children have more than another child.

The example below for more explanation on this:

The output that I need to edit is as below:

```
X1  Y6  ID=0
X1  Y6  ID=1
X1  Y7  ID=0
X1  Y8  ID=0

X2  Y6  ID=0
X2  Y6  ID=1
X2  Y7  ID=0

X3  Y6  ID=0
X3  Y6  ID=1
```

=============

The needed output should be:

```
X1  Y6  ID=0
        ID=1
    Y7  ID=0
    Y8  ID=0

X2  Y6  ID=0
        ID=1
    Y7  ID=0

X3  Y6  ID=0
        ID=1
```

So, we have for example X1 having 3 children Y6,Y7 and Y8 while Y6 have 2 IDs and Y7,Y8 have only one ID=0 each

The output needed might be different but we still need to understand that X1 have three Ys and ID for each Y

I tried many for loops with awk and greps but couldn't get what is needed

Your help is much appreciated !

Comment: "I tried many for loops with awk and greps" Please post the results of some of the loops so that we can help you help yourself. Asking for code without showing effort is a surefire way to get downvoted.

Comment: $ for i in 1 2 3
>  do
> echo X$i
> grep -p X$i file | grep Y|awk {'print $2'}
> done

but the output was corrupted .. I got the header with it's children however I couldn't get the children of the children

Comment: Please, add the code to the question and format it properly. Help us to help you.

Comment: try `awk -F'\t' '$0==""{print;next} {if(last1==$1)level=(last2==$2?2:1);else level=0} {last1=$1;last2=$2} level>=2{$2=""} level>=1{$1=""} {print}'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this `awk` script:

```
awk -v OFS="  " '
{
   for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {       # Loop through all fields
      if(last[i]==$i && i<3)  # Check if field is different than previous line
         gsub(/./," ",$i)     # Replace all character by spaces
      printf $i OFS           # Print the field with the separator
      if($i !~ / +/)          # Check if the field contains only spaces
         last[i]=$i           # Store the last field
   }
   printf ORS                 # No more fields, print the new line
}' file
```

Comment: another quick question, what if the second  column was not arranged as Y6>Y7>Y8 ...?

Comment: @mshafey As long as fields are differents it will be printed

Comment: but i still need to list 2nd column once along with its children ... don't want it repeated ...

Comment: @mshafey just add `/^$/{delete last}` at the end of the script and that will ensure the first line of each block is printed

Comment: After the lines `X1  Y8  ID=0` and `X2  Y8  ID=0` the second Y8 will get lost.
`

Comment: I don't know what the OP wants when one of the first 2 fields have a different length than 2. Something like `X9  Y8  ID=0` and `X10 Y8  ID=0`.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to remember the different fields from the previous line. You should use an `awk` for better performance, here you find a verbose a prototype.

```
cmd_generating_output | while read -r x y i; do
   # check for empty line, can be skipped
   if [ -z "i$x" ]; then
      echo
   else
      if [ "$x" = "${lastx}" ]; then
         newx=" "
         if [ "$y" = "${lasty}" ]; then
            newy=" "
         else
            newy="$y"
         fi
      else
         newx="$x"
         newy="$y"
      fi
      printf "%-4s%-4s%s\n" "${newx}" "${newy}" "$i"
      lastx=$x
      lasty=$y
   fi
done
```